# How to calculate the probability of a raindrop falling exactly in a given location?

Tags: probability

I have a square board of finite size, and a circular target marked on it. Now I let a drop of rain fall on this board where it will hit a random location and occupy a circular area. How do I find the probability of that drop landing completely inside the bounds of the target?

Comment: "occupy a circular area" Is the radius of the area known?

Comment: Yes, all of the areas (board, target and drop) have a known size

Comment: Is the random location of the centre of the circle uniformly distributed in the square? Or on a square of side $S-2r$ where $r$ is the radius of the drop. Or somewhere else?

Comment: André: I didn't think about that. I'd say whatever makes the problem simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the size of the square.

Let $R$ denote the radius of the circular target.

Let $r$ denote the radius of the circular area created by the rain-drop.

Then the probability of the rain-drop landing completely inside the bounds of the target is:

$$\frac{\pi(R-r)^2}{S}$$

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean the probability is 0 if the target and drop are of the same size?

Comment: @Fönsi: Yes, because the drop will have to land exactly in the middle of the target. That is $1$ point out of $\infty$ possible points to land on.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense

Comment: Providing a formula for the result without explaining to the OP how you arrived at it is probably not very useful as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to formalise your question. Forget raindrops, targets and boards, they are not mathematical objects. I will restate your question to an equivalent mathematical question.

> Let $S=[0,a]\times [0,a]$ be a square in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $C=\{x\in S: ||x-x_0||\leq R\}$ be the circle with center $x_0$ and radius $R$, intersected with $S$.

The question you ask is then

> Given a radius $r$, if i randomly select a center $x_r$, what is the probability that the circle $\{x\in S: ||x-x_r||\leq r\}$ is a subset of $C$?

You can now, with some sketching, see that this is equivalent to asking

> Given a radius $r$, if I randomly select a point $x_r$, what is the probability that it lies in the circle $\{x\in S: ||x-x_0||\leq R-r\}$?

Which is an easy question to answer.